# Python, numpy sort array

Tags: python, numpy

I'am using numpy and have an array (ndarray type) which contain some values. Shape of this array 1000x1500. I reshaped it

```
brr = np.reshape(arr, arr.shape[0]*arr.shape[1])
```

when I trying

```
brr.reverse()
AttributeError: ‘numpy.ndarray’ object has no attribute ‘reverse’
```

get error.
How I can sort this array ?

Comment: what are you expecting `reverse()` to do?

Comment: Doesn't solve your problem, but to make your code a little neater and more efficient you can use `arr.size` instead of `arr.shape[0]*arr.shape[1]`.

Comment: I want to sort it descending. Btw sort() give the same error

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you just want to reverse it:

```
brr[:] = brr[::-1]
```

Actually, this reverses along axis 0. You could also revert on any other axis, if the array has more than one.

To sort in reverse order:

```
>>> arr = np.random.random((1000,1500))
>>> brr = np.reshape(arr, arr.shape[0]*arr.shape[1])
>>> brr.sort()
>>> brr = brr[::-1]
>>> brr
array([  9.99999960e-01,   9.99998167e-01,   9.99998114e-01, ...,
     3.79672182e-07,   3.23871190e-07,   8.34517810e-08])
```

or, using argsort:

```
>>> arr = np.random.random((1000,1500))
>>> brr = np.reshape(arr, arr.shape[0]*arr.shape[1])
>>> sort_indices = np.argsort(brr)[::-1]
>>> brr[:] = brr[sort_indices]
>>> brr
array([  9.99999849e-01,   9.99998950e-01,   9.99998762e-01, ...,
         1.16993050e-06,   1.68760770e-07,   6.58422260e-08])
```

Comment: No, it is unsorted, I have to sort it descending

Comment: Thanks! Tried argsort() with no luck. Did not knew about [::-1]

Comment: `brr = np.sort(brr)[::-1]`

Answer (score 16):

Try this for sorting in descending order ,

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,3,4,5,6])
print -np.sort(-a)
```

Answer (score 4):

To sort a 1d array in descending order, pass reverse=True to `sorted`.
As [@Erik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/832218/erik) pointed out, `sorted` will first make a copy of the list and then sort it in reverse.

```
import numpy as np
import random
x = np.arange(0, 10)
x_sorted_reverse = sorted(x, reverse=True)
```

Comment: sorted uses python's iterable sort, which will first copy all of the data into a list and then do the sort in reverse. While this does indeed result in a reverse sorting of the data, it doesn't do so in numpy, and generally removes any benefit of using numpy.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, Erik. I added it to the answer.