# Sorting values in an array: 'reverse' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting

I try to sort values in an array in descending order. If I try it in ascending order it works, but when i do it descending I get an error.

```
e = np.array([[5.,3.,8.],[6.,7.,1.],[4.,8.,2.]])
e.sort()
```

result:

```
e = array([[3.,5.,8.],[1.,6.,7.],[2.,4.,8.]])
```

now in reverse order:

```
  e.sort(reverse=True)
```

result:

```
TypeError: 'reverse' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

I also tried `e.sort(key=itemgetter(1))` after `from operator import itemgetter` but the same error appears ('reverse' is replaced by 'key').

Why is this the case? Why does it not work? Why this error (this is the way to use key or reverse right)?

Comment: I've found my result here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875248/python-numpy-sort-array/14875366) 
`f = -np.sort(-e)` worked perfect!

Answer (score 2):

You couldn't use the `key` or `reverse` keyword arguments according to [numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html). You can sort the array in ascending order and then reverse it with the `[::-1]` slice or use the `reversed()` view.

Answer (score 0):

Try using fliplr after sitting in ascending order https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html#numpy.fliplr

Comment: I've also some nan values in my dataset which should stay at the end of the array. By using fliplr these would be put in front. Otherwise this would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this the case? Why does it not work?

Simply because [numpy's sort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sort.html#numpy.ndarray.sort) function doesn't supply that functionality.

One way to "fix" this problem is to argsort on the column of interest.  You can then reverse the output and use that to index `e` to get the items sorted as you wish:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> e = np.array([[5.,3.,8.],[6.,7.,1.],[4.,8.,2.]])
>>> e
array([[ 5.,  3.,  8.],
       [ 6.,  7.,  1.],
       [ 4.,  8.,  2.]])
>>> col = 0
>>> idx_asc = np.argsort(e[:, col])
>>> idx_desc = idx_asc[::-1]
>>> e[idx_desc]
array([[ 6.,  7.,  1.],
       [ 5.,  3.,  8.],
       [ 4.,  8.,  2.]])
```

Note that this approach is less flexible (and less convenient) than being able to pass a `key` and `reverse=True`.  Specifically, if you want to sort on multiple columns to break ties, this approach fails.

Comment: No column is of special interest, all rows should be sorted indivudually.

Comment: @SVerhoef -- I guess I don't understand what you're getting at with they `key=itemgetter(1)` then ...