# How to plot a single column based on its sorted values

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

Lets assume I have a dataframe with one column.
I sorted it and when I tried to plot the sorted values, the plot is getting plotted as per indices not as per the sorted values.

How to achieve a plot which is plotted based on the sorted values?

I want the plot to be curve from top declining towards to bottom.

Ex code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a=pd.DataFrame()
a['col']=(4,5,8,10,1,0,15,20)
a_sorted=a.sort_values(by='col',ascending=False)
plt.plot(a_s)
```

Comment: What do you mean? If the dataframe has only one column, the other axis must be the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need default index by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) and `drop=True` parameter:

```
a_sorted=a.sort_values(by='col',ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then also working [`Series.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.html):

```
a_sorted.plot()
```

Another solution is ploting numpy 1d array by [`Series.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html):

```
a_sorted=a.sort_values(by='col',ascending=False)
plt.plot(a_sorted.values)
```

Or use [sorting in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24996734/2901002):

```
plt.plot(-np.sort(-a['col']))
```

Comment: this 'reset_index(drop=True)' solved my problem.Thanks.